# Изображение по умолчанию при использовании Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Как вставить на страницу изображение по умолчание в случае если изображение которое вернет thymeleaf будет равным null.

```
img  th:src="@{'/person/personimage/' + ${person.id} }" width="200" height="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img th:src="@{'/person/personimage/' + (${person.id} :? 'default-image.jpg') }">
```

Comment: какая-то ошибка в синтаксисе ... не могу разобраться

Comment: подчеркивает двоеточие